# Is it a good practice to use `where 1=2` query for an empty list in MyBatis?

Tags: sql, mybatis

I often query a list of records from a list. For example:

There is a list `list = [1, 2, 3];`

and SQL defination in Mybatis:

```
<select id="selectByIds" parameterType="java.util.List" resultType="...">
    SELECT * FROM table1
    WHERE id in
    <foreach collection="list" index="index" item="id" open="(" close=")" separator=",">
        #{id}
    </foreach>
</select>
```

But the `list` should not be empty, otherwise the SQL will become `SELECT * FROM table1 where id in ()` and the SQL will throw an exception.

In order to return empty records while the `list` is null or empty, I change the SQL to use `where 1=2` to make sql return empty.

```
<select id="selectByIds" parameterType="java.util.List" resultType="...">
    SELECT * FROM table1
    WHERE 
    <choose>
        <when test="list!=null and list.size()>0">
            id in
            <foreach collection="list" index="index" item="id" open="(" close=")" separator=",">
                #{id}
            </foreach>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            1=2
        </otherwise>
    </choose>
</select>
```

I am concerned about `where 1=2`. Is it a good practice to use it? Is there any other way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2):

The better way to handle this is to not execute the query at all if it is known that the query will return empty result set for empty list.

This will save you roundtrip to database, execution of the query (which you already know the result for) and mapping results back.

Comment: The actual situation may be more complicated, such as the list query as part of the `union`, you can not determine whether the final result is empty.

Comment: If it is part of the union then it is better to wrap that branch of the union in `choose/when`.

Answer (score 1):

in general conditions should be checked **before** executing methods, functions and/or procedures. otherwise its just a random call of it.